# How to navigate to a specific screen on clicking a link from email relaying(fetch and submit) the code from the link?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, navigation, deep-linking

I have tried the deep linking in android.manifest file. The link is working but it not navigating to the screen i want.

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

it is giving me this error.
this is the code i wrote for navigation

```
const resetLinking = {
     prefixes: ['forgot://password'],
     config: {
         screens: {
            ForgotPassword:{
                path: 'ForgotPassword',
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

and also How do i obtain the code forgot://password/123456 at the end of the link
this is the code i wrote for fetching the code

```
const resetLinking = {
     prefixes: ['forgot://password','/code],
     config: {
         screens: {
            ForgotPassword:{
                path: 'ForgotPassword/code',
                 parse: {
                     code: (code) => `${code}`
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: could you post some code pls?

Comment: added please check